# Xcode iPhone: New Project Template, Combine?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

This question is simple... you have a choice of which Template you'd like to use when creating a new iPhone application in Xcode.

What if I choose a View-Based, but I need a Navigation-Based application too? Can you combine the various templates within a project? I mean, is it just a matter of creating a new .xib file and dragging on the various UI components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation based template is also view based. Look at the code, the navigation based template contains a rootViewController which loads its view from a xib file.

You cannot combine templates automatically you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I do see that the Navigation-Based inherits from View-Based. So these are just starting point... from there, you can create other .xib files and utilize those elements within the header file. There's essentially nothing stopping me from combining a whole slew of UI components in one .xib file.

Comment: Right, that's what many developers do. You can create views without IB but maintenance of code can be harder than pushing some pixels in IB.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create custom templates as you want. You just need to pick a template from Xcode then you can modify it as you want and just place it on a proper location.

Read my this blog post for a better understanding - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/how-to-create-xcode-project-templates/